# VMWare Workstation 10/11 Windows 7 not enough physical memory is available to power on this virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

- Workstation 10.0.4
- Win7 x64 SP1
- 32GB RAM
- Asus Z87-Pro (Intel Virtualization enabled, memory scrambler/remap disabled)
- Intel 4770K

Images of error and free memory in Windows:

[image]

[image]

**Problem:**

- Using more than 2.8GB of RAM when allowing most memory to be swapped
  gives an error about not enough memory available.
- I am able to boot up if I limit one VM to 2.8GB RAM and enable swap
  most. The VM will eventually stall if I attempt to use all 2.8GB
  requiring force close of `vmware-vmx.exe`.
- I can't use the options to allocate all or swap some memory at all.

**Steps tried to resolve:**

- Uninstall/Reinstall did not fix,   /clean did not fix either
- Workstation 11 beta gives same error
- Run as Administrator
- Tried `vmmon.disableHostParameters = “TRUE”` in `config.ini`.

Comment: The images are pretty hard to read as is. It would probably help to crop them

Comment: Right click "open image in new tab" to see the full image.  The image basically just says that I should reduce the VMs settings to 2600MB and increase the amount of memory reserved for all VMs up to 2400MB even though it is set to 12GB globally.

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [VMware Blog](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/workstation-10-issue-recent-microsoft-windows-8-1-update.html), Windows 8.1 Update KB2995388 introduced this error in VMware Workstation 10 (and 11 beta and VMware Player 6). On my Z97a Motherboard with Devil's Canyon processor, prior to Workstation 10.0.4, I had to uninstall the Windows Update to get VMware working again. Setting vmmon.disableHostParameters = "TRUE" in the config.ini was not adequate to work around this problem for me prior to Workstation 10.0.4.

However, with [VMware 10.0.4](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/vmware-workstation-10-player-6-update-now-available.html), my system is now working fine with the KB Update installed. Make sure to reboot after installing / uninstalling the various items since the configuration files are read by services on reboot.

If 10.0.4 doesn't work for you after a reboot, maybe you can figure out if there are equivalent Windows 7 patches corresponding to KB2995388 and try uninstalling those and follow-up with a support case at VMware since I'm sure they'll want to know about your situation.

Comment: Except form the images above we can clearly see Excite Networks is running on a Windows 7 host, not 8.1. That update does not apply here.

Comment: Good point, that KB is not directly applicable. I was hoping that it would at least give Excite Networks something to look into. I did not see an obvious-to-me equivalent roll-up update for Windows 7 on the Microsoft site, although there may be one, I don't know how to figure out corresponding patch sets. If there are equivalent patches for Windows 7, then maybe uninstalling them would be a workaround.  I'll update my answer although as you point out, there may not be an equivalent triggering update.

Comment: AFAIK, there are not. The memory bugs in 8.1 pertain to the kernel and that's a whole 'nother story.